# Load different views dependant on user role asp.net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I am new to asp.netcore MVC

I am wanting to load different views dependant on the user's role e.g.

```
if (role == "Admin")
   return view("admin")
else if (role == "Other")
   return  view("index")
```

I know you can use the [authorize(Role = ... and the asp.net core identity api.

I was wondering if anyone can point me to a good tutorial that dealt with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some related articles about using Asp.net Core Identity to manage users and roles, and implement Role-Based Authentication. You could refer to them:

[Introduction to Identity on ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

[How to work with Roles in ASP.NET Core Identity](https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-identity-roles/)

[Role-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[Adding Role Authorization to a ASP.NET MVC Core Application](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/adding-role-authorization-to-a-asp-net-mvc-core-application/)

Then, after configuring the application using Asp.net Core identity and add the Role authorization.

In the view page, you could use the `Context.User.IsInRole` method to check whether current user is in the specified role. Then, load the related content. Code like this:

```
    @if (Context.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    { 
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Role" asp-action="Index">Role</a>
        </li>
    }
```

In the controller, to return different view based on the role. We could use `HttpContext.User.IsInRole` method to check whether user in the specified role. For example:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    { 
        if (HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            return View("Privacy");
        } 
        return View();
    }
```

Besides, we could also use the [`UserManager.IsInRoleAsync()` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.isinroleasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to check it.

By using the above sample code, the result like this:

[image]